# tikz matrix of multipart nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix, multipart-node

I can't figure out how one puts data of a multipart nodes in a matrix. Is this allowed ?
The Following MRE works well

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees, shapes, arrows, arrows.meta, matrix, calc, graphs,
  plotmarks, backgrounds, cd}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2] at (1,1) {1 \nodepart{second} A};
    \matrix (M) [matrix of math nodes,
    nodes={rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2}] {
      X & 2 \\
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

However if I replace the X in the matrix by `{1 \nodepart{second} A}` with or without curly brace, I got

```
ERROR: Missing } inserted.

--- TeX said ---
<inserted text> 
                }
l.11       {1 \nodepart{second}
                                A} & 2 \\
--- HELP ---
TeX has become confused. The position indicated by the error locator
is probably beyond the point where the incorrect input is.
```

Am I doing some obvious mistake ? Is there a workaround ?

Comment: just use `matrix` and `shapes.multipart` library https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf

Comment: @BlackMild This really solves all the problems ! Thanks. If you post your comment as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: I don't understand the answers to this Q. The real problem is a [bug with `execute at end node` which is used by `matrix of math nodes` to insert the `$`](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/1155) where this `$` is inserted twice for the first nodepart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is okay; I just use `matrix` and `shapes.multipart` libraries.

One more thing: essentially, TikZ has the only one command: `\path`; and TikZ drawing is just putting `node`s and `pic`s along a path. Therefore, although [the PGF manual](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) usually write

```
\matrix [matrix of nodes] {...}
```

but in my experience, it's better (less errors may arise) to write

```
\path (2,3) node[matrix,matrix of nodes] {...}
```

Likewise, I like writing `\path  (1,1) node[] {};` instead of `\node[] {} at (1,1);`

Below is your code with my writing style. Hope this helps!

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart, matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path 
(1,1) node[rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2]{1 \nodepart{second} $A$};
\path 
(0,0) node[matrix,matrix of math nodes,
nodes={rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2}] (M) {
        X & 2 \\
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see, your question is about TikZ matrices in LaTeX. The issue you're encountering is due to how the node naming in TikZ matrices works. When you define a matrix of nodes in TikZ, each cell of the matrix automatically gets a node name following the pattern `matrixname-rownumber-columnnumber`. For example, the first cell in a matrix named `M` would be `M-1-1`.

In your example, you're placing a node inside a matrix cell, which is also a node. This means that the node inside the cell doesn't automatically get a name following the usual pattern, hence the error "No shape named `M-1-1' is known."

A workaround for this is to manually name the inner node, like this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart, matrix}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix (M) [matrix of nodes,
    nodes={rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2, draw, anchor=center}] {
      \node[name=M-1-1] {1 \nodepart{second} A}; & 2 \\
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In this code, `\node[name=M-1-1] {1 \nodepart{second} A}` names the node inside the first cell of the matrix `M-1-1`. Now you can refer to this node using the name `M-1-1` in other parts of your TikZ picture.

Please let me know if this solves your problem or if you need further assistance.

Comment: Excellent. Together with a macro `\newcommand\nd[2]{\node {#1 \nodepart{second} #2};}` to keep things not too verbose this totally solve my problem ! Thanks !

Comment: Actually this doesn't really solve it. After that the node are note named anymore... `No shape named `M-1-1' is known.`

Comment: Edited the answer

Comment: Thanks ! However In my real application I have a 12x12 matrix. I don't want to specify all the positions by hand. It turns out that @Black Mild comment solve the problem. Again thanks for you effort !

Comment: Anyway, Gabriel's answer needs to be upvoted (I did, but someone downvoted it)